# Bootstrap Light Box not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**Edited:**

Below js code generate a modal like this
[image]

but sometime it fails.And it look like this
[image]

So i want a solution for that problem

This is the html structure

```
 <div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="gallery-item shad" style="height : 100px; width:143px;">
     <a href="#">
        @if(empty($service->image)))
          {{HTML::image('image/no-image.png',null,array('style'=>'height : 100px;'))}}
           @else
            {{HTML::image('image/'.$service->image,null,array('style'=>'height : 100px;'))}}
        @endif
     </a>
</div>
```

file.js

```
/* copy loaded thumbnails into carousel */
$('.gallery-image img').on('load', function() {
    /*this section execute when i reload the page*/
    console.log('not working');
}).each(function(i) {
   if(this.complete) {
     var item = $('<div class="item"></div>');
     var itemDiv = $(this).parent();

     $(itemDiv.html()).appendTo(item);
     item.appendTo('.carousel-inner');
     if (i==0){ // set first item active
        item.addClass('active');
     }
   }
});

/* activate the carousel */
$('#modalCarousel').carousel({interval:false});

/* when clicking a thumbnail */
$('.gallery-image').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var idx = $(this).parents().parents().index();
   var id = parseInt(idx);
   $('#myModal').modal('show'); // show the modal
   $('#modalCarousel').carousel(id); // slide carousel to selected
});
```

this code works when i load the page for very first time but when i reload the page and click on the image this code is not work working

Comment: Unable to understand what you are trying to say! Can you rephrase?

Comment: i update the problem now.Please have a look

Comment: Super, so where exactly are you setting the contents of the modal window?

Comment: first few lines of file.js file

Comment: Check out ma answer!

Comment: when model not display the image,i show a message on console as like "not working".
which i write on the $('.gallelry-image img').on('load'......);

Answer (score 0):

I can understand that you are setting the contents of the modal window on the first few lines of the JavaScript. Try to set it in the `click` event:

```
$('.gallery-image').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var idx = $(this).parents().parents().index();
   var id = parseInt(idx);
   $('#myModal').modal('show'); // show the modal
   $('#modalCarousel').carousel(id); // slide carousel to selected
   // Update the modal window contents here.
});
```

Comment: You need to do it there exactly!

Comment: i did that exactly you said.but the problem is not there.

Comment: i need js code which appends all the images to the modal when the page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have find a solution

```
$('.carousel-inner').find('.item').first().addClass('active');
/* when clicking a thumbnail */
$('.gallery-image').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var idx = $(this).parents().parents().index();
    var id = parseInt(idx);

    $("#myModal").modal("show");
    $('#modalCarousel').carousel(id);
});
```